# Can't understand this regex format (Phone number)

Tags: php, regex

I have to format a phone number according to this regex:

```
/^\\+([0-9]){1,3}\\.([0-9]\\ ?){6,14}$/
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out the second half of this. My best efforts have me at

1. It has to start with a backslash
2. Then 1-3 digits
3. Then another backslash followed by any character
4. 6-14 iterations of `([0-9]\\ ?)`
5. End of string

If I'm right so far, I can't figure out the format of #4. Or am I totally wrong?

Let's say I have this phone number: +0018005551212 or 18005551212

How would I form this number? Answer would be great but an explanation would be even better. Thanks!!!

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://regex101.com/r/dK8aM0/1) for auto explanation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the backslashes are just to escape the plus sign, the dot and the space (which doesn't need it).  The author may not have realized he could use a single-quotes to avoid having to escape the backslashes themselves: `'/^\+([0-9]){1,3}\.([0-9]\ ?){6,14}$/'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in all likelihood, the `\\` is an escaped `\`, needed because there is another interpretive layer in there that will detect escape characters. You often see this in `bash` (as one example) when using double-quoted strings:

```
pax> echo '\' | sed 's/\\/x/'
x
pax> echo '\' | sed "s/\\\\/x/"
x

pax> echo '\' | sed 's/\/x/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated 's' command
pax> echo '\' | sed "s/\\/x/"
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated 's' command
```

With the double-quoted string, `bash` itself interprets the escapes before `sed` ever sees them, so you need to double-escape. With the single quotes, `bash` does not interpret the escapes in the string so they're passed to `sed` as is.

That's based on the fact that, while international phone numbers can begin with `+`, I've *never* seen one with a backslash in it.

So the rules are:

```
^                   start of string
\\+                 a literal +
([0-9]){1,3}        1-3 digits
\\.                 a literal .
([0-9]\\ ?){6,14}   6-14 digits, each with an optional following apace
$                   end of string
```

Comment: You're 100% right and I don't know how I missed that. I spent an hour swearing at this API for telling me to format the phone number in such a stupid, escaped way, and I really only needed +001.8005551212. Thanks for the fresh eyes!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation of your current regex, along with some examples which it can match.

[REGEX EXPLANATION](https://regex101.com/r/dK8aM0/5)

```
^                   assert position at start of a line
\\+                 matches the character \ literally one or more times
([0-9]){1,3}        capturing group matching a digit between 1 to 3 times
\\                  matches the character \ literally
.                   matches any character (except newline)
(                   start of another capturing group
  [0-9]             any digit between 0 to 9   
  \\                matches the character \ literally 
   ?                match a space zero or one time
){6,14}             repeat this pattern 6 to 14 times
$                   assert position at end of a line
```

Your current regex matches following examples (which don't look like phone numbers to me):

```
\1\+9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 
\\\12\79\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 
\123\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 
\\124\A9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 
\\124\_9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\9\ 
\\124\_9\ 9\ 9\ 9\ 9\9\ 9\9\9\ 9\9\9\
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the explanation and examples? Please care to comment when downvoting so the answer can be improved.

Comment: But, it doesn't look like so if you follow the link in the answer.

Comment: AKS, it's almost certainly due to the fact that no phone number standard in existence uses the backslash character (as you yourself note in the answer), but they *do* use `+`. That means, as per my answer, it's a double-escaped `+` rather than one or more backslashes. But I feel for you on the downvote since my own answer is similarly treated, despite the fact the OP accepted it and despite its obvious brilliance :-)

Comment: Well, I think a downvote should always be followed by comments otherwise it is not worth. I still wonder why the same code on regex101 displays this different behavior.

Comment: AKS, if you change all the double backslashes into singles (as an extra escape-interpretive layer would), you'll get a different explanation and good results from numbers like `+613.4455 27 27`.